# How Do Professionals Send HTML Emails?

Tags: html, email

Happy New Year!

So I've been teaching myself HTML5 and CSS3 by watching YouTube videos and coding in VS Code. I am now capable of creating responsive web pages using media queries.

What I would like to know is..

How do professionals send HTML emails? I would like to try doing this for the first time.

I've seen YouTube videos where they use Google Chrome's developer tool to inspect some placeholder text and then copy and paste their code in to the developer tool editor but this seems really amateurish to me? Like a hack rather than a long term tool.

Is there a commonly used application or program that is most popular among professional HTML Email Developers? If so what is it please?

I will just add that I do have some server space to store my images for the email. I just want to know how to send the HTML/CSS code as an email. I'm planning on doing it regularly so can justify using a professional app or program.

Thanks very much for your help and happy new year! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I want to send multiple HTML emails, I typically use [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer), an npm package to use with nodeJS. This requires some JavaScript background and having nodeJS installed on your computer. Before I knew JavaScript, I used to just send HTML messages using Developer Tools and then using a template saver like [this one by SendPulse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-email-template-power/abokklkondgpdlcajcjiobegghjfccih). If I find anything new, I'll update you.